# How to change the morphTime at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I copied the whole switch/case part to the Update to be able to change the modes also at runtime.

but I want also to be able to change the morphTime at runtime without the need to switch a mode first. for example if the enum mode is now MultiColorMorph and then if i'm changing only  the morphTime then affect the change on the current mode.

I'm not sure about the other modes but the two modes that use the morphTime are :

RandomSingleColorMorphing and RandomMultiColorMorphing

```
IEnumerator RandomSingleColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;
        Color initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
        //this reduces colorkey amount to 2 just in case.
        SetSingleColor2(lineRendererToChange, initialColor);

        while (true)
        {
            initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
            Color targetColor = RandomColor();
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                Color currentColor = Color.Lerp(initialColor, targetColor, progress);
                SetSingleColor(lineRendererToChange, currentColor);
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

And

```
IEnumerator RandomMultiColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys;
            GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = GenerateRandomColorKeys(initialColorKeys);
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                GradientColorKey[] currentColorKeys = GradientColorKeyLerp(initialColorKeys, newColorKeys, progress);
                Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
                tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys;
                lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

The full code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class LineRendererColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimationType { None, SingleColorMorph, MultiColorMorph, Shuffle, Shift };
    public AnimationType myAnimationType;
    LineRenderer myLineRenderer;
    public float morphTime;

    void Start()
    {
        myLineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        switch (myAnimationType)
        {
            case AnimationType.SingleColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomSingleColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.MultiColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomMultiColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shuffle:
                StartCoroutine(ShuffleGradient(myLineRenderer, .5f));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shift:
                StartCoroutine(AnimateLoop(myLineRenderer));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        switch (myAnimationType)
        {
            case AnimationType.SingleColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomSingleColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.MultiColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomMultiColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shuffle:
                StartCoroutine(ShuffleGradient(myLineRenderer, .5f));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shift:
                StartCoroutine(AnimateLoop(myLineRenderer));
                break;
        }
    }

    void SetSingleColor(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.startColor = newColor;
        lineRendererToChange.endColor = newColor;
    }

    void SetSingleColor2(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = new Gradient();

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];
        tempColorKeys[0] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 0);
        tempColorKeys[1] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 1);

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    void SetSingleColor3(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = tempGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            tempColorKeys[i].color = newColor;
        }

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    IEnumerator ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, float waitTime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ShuffleGradient(targetLineRenderer);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

    void ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Color tempColor = newColorKeys[i].color;
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, newColorKeys.Length - 1);
            newColorKeys[i].color = newColorKeys[randomIndex].color;
            newColorKeys[randomIndex].color = tempColor;
        }
        Gradient tempGradient = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient;
        tempGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys;
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }


    IEnumerator RandomMultiColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys;
            GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = GenerateRandomColorKeys(initialColorKeys);
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                GradientColorKey[] currentColorKeys = GradientColorKeyLerp(initialColorKeys, newColorKeys, progress);
                Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
                tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys;
                lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    GradientColorKey[] GradientColorKeyLerp(GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys, GradientColorKey[] endColorKeys, float progress)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[initialColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = Color.Lerp(initialColorKeys[i].color, endColorKeys[i].color, progress);
            newColorKeys[i].time = initialColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //assigns new color to each colorkey and uses Time from incomingColorKeys
    GradientColorKey[] GenerateRandomColorKeys(GradientColorKey[] incomingColorKeys)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[incomingColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = RandomColor();
            newColorKeys[i].time = incomingColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //asumes Single color, 2 colorkeys
    IEnumerator RandomSingleColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;
        Color initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
        //this reduces colorkey amount to 2 just in case.
        SetSingleColor2(lineRendererToChange, initialColor);

        while (true)
        {
            initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
            Color targetColor = RandomColor();
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                Color currentColor = Color.Lerp(initialColor, targetColor, progress);
                SetSingleColor(lineRendererToChange, currentColor);
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //Basically Color.Lerp?
    Color ColorLerpMath(Color firstColor, Color secondColor, float progress)
    {
        Vector3 firstRGB = new Vector3(firstColor.r, firstColor.g, firstColor.b);
        Vector3 secondRGB = new Vector3(secondColor.r, secondColor.g, secondColor.b);
        Vector3 difference = secondRGB - firstRGB;
        Vector3 lerpedRGB = firstRGB + (progress * difference);
        return new Color(lerpedRGB.x, lerpedRGB.y, lerpedRGB.z);
    }

    Color RandomColor()
    {
        return new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
    }

    //returns the gradient with a copy of the first key for intersection purposes.
    Gradient AddInitialCopy(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> newColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        Color interSectionColor = newColorKeys[0].color;
        newColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(interSectionColor, 0));
        Gradient newInitGradient = new Gradient();
        newInitGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys.ToArray();
        return newInitGradient;
    }

    //remove first and last keys since they dont shift.
    List<GradientColorKey> RemoveFirstAndLast(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(currentColorKeys.Count - 1);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentColorKeys;
    }

    Color GetIntersectionColor(List<GradientColorKey> incomingKeys, int lowestIndex, int highestIndex)
    {
        Color firstColor = incomingKeys[lowestIndex].color;
        Color lastColor = incomingKeys[highestIndex].color;
        float distance = 1 - (incomingKeys[highestIndex].time - incomingKeys[lowestIndex].time);
        float colorLerpAmount = (1f - incomingKeys[highestIndex].time) / distance; ;
        Color newIntersectionColor = Color.Lerp(lastColor, firstColor, colorLerpAmount);
        return newIntersectionColor;
    }

    //accepts max 7 colors, 1st and last should be at 0 and 1
    IEnumerator AnimateLoop(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float movementPerTick = .001f)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = AddInitialCopy(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);

        while (true)
        {
            List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = RemoveFirstAndLast(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);
            float highestTime = 0;
            float lowestTime = 1;
            int highestIndex = currentColorKeys.Count - 1;
            int lowestIndex = 0;
            //Move all inner ones.
            for (int i = 0; i < currentColorKeys.Count; i++)
            {
                GradientColorKey tempColorKey = currentColorKeys[i];
                float newTime = tempColorKey.time + movementPerTick;

                if (newTime > 1)
                {
                    newTime = newTime - 1;
                }
                tempColorKey.time = newTime;
                currentColorKeys[i] = tempColorKey;
                if (newTime < lowestTime)
                {
                    lowestTime = newTime;
                    lowestIndex = i;
                }
                if (newTime > highestTime)
                {
                    highestTime = newTime;
                    highestIndex = i;
                }
            }
            Color newIntersectionColor = GetIntersectionColor(currentColorKeys, lowestIndex, highestIndex);
            currentColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 0));
            currentColorKeys.Add(new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 1));
            Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
            tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys.ToArray();
            lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void AssignGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, Gradient newGradient)
    {
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = newGradient;
    }

    void DrawTestLine()
    {
        Vector3 firstPos = new Vector3(-5, 0, 0);
        Vector3 secondPos = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        int resolution = 100;
        myLineRenderer.positionCount = resolution;
        myLineRenderer.SetPositions(MakeLine(firstPos, secondPos, 100));
    }

    //makes a line from point A to point B with resolution of size points
    Vector3[] MakeLine(Vector3 initPos, Vector3 endPos, int points)
    {
        Vector3 difference = endPos - initPos;
        Vector3[] newLine = new Vector3[points];
        Vector3 differencePerPoint = difference / (float)(points - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            newLine[i] = initPos + (differencePerPoint * i);
        }
        return newLine;
    }

}
```

Comment: either way you do not want to start a new concurrent coroutine **every frame** ...